# Adding a very simple highscore to cocos2d iphone app using a CCTimer

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'v been looking around on google and I can't find any way to make a highscore app based on a value of a CCTimer. I get that I could try to convert that value to a string or float but i'm not exactly sure how. I read up on cocos live but it doesn't seem to work for me and its a little bigger than I need. I don't need global leaderboards but that would be nice. If someone has any suggestions to start that would be really helpful. If anyone needs my source code I can post that for you too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get what you mean, you are trying to make a score based on the amount of time passed..

Add a variable.. If you call your ccTimer every 0.03 seconds, you can do something like this in the function that you called:

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime)delay
{
timePassed +=0.03;
//blah blah blah
}
```

So when you need to get the score based on time passed, just read the timePassed variable..

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but really I am new to cocos2d I'v just switched over from using straight up xcode and C+ so I'm still a bit sketch on adding things like textfields and how to tell values to display in them. Sorry for my stupidity but it would be really helpful if you could be a little more specific

Comment: timePassed is a float.. you can try calling the tick selector first..
something like:
 [self schedule:@selector(tick:) interval: 0.03f];